# logic of thread.join() add after main loop (c++ boost/thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, boost, program-entry-point

i have this example code:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void hello()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello thread!" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::thread thrd(&hello);

    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello main!" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
    thrd.join();

    return 0;
}
```

after run, i got results:

```
Hello main!
Hello thread!
Hello main!
Hello thread!
Hello main!
Hello main!
Hello thread!
Hello main!
Hello thread!
Hello main!
...
```

i thought the main loop (while(1)) should block the process, and thread `thrd` should not be invoked. but the result looks not like this.

is this result right? what's the logic of the position in the code of thread.join() ?
any official doc could i refer to ?

thx

Comment: Threads are concurrent. This is not javascript where only one thing can happen at a time.

Comment: `hello()` is subject to execution the time `thrd` is created.

Comment: "what's the logic of the position in the code of thread.join() ?" that position lacks any logic as the code is not designed to reach that line.

Comment: main loop (while(1)) should block only the main thread, not the whole process

Comment: Another way of saying what @ÖöTiib said; The `thrd.join()` statement is _dead code._ That is: Code that is included in a program, but which will never be executed by the program.

Comment: if you want threads that don't execute concurrently, look into coroutines

Answer (score 0):

> i thought the main loop (`while(1) {...}`) should block the process...

Then you are *completely* misunderstanding the purpose of threads. The whole point of `boost::thread thrd(&hello);` is that it runs the `hello()` function *independently* of the main thread.

When we first learned to write code, we stepped through it using pencil and paper. Then we learned that "the computer" executes the code in the same way as when we did it "by hand."

But saying "the computer" doesn't adequately describe it if the program uses multiple threads. It's better to say, that when your program starts, a *thread* steps through, executing it line by line. And then if one of those lines creates another thread, then those to threads *both* commence to step through, side-by-side, (a.k.a., [*concurrently*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)),) each with its own set of local variables, and sharing the global variables.